# Records inserted into my table through SQL client are not showing up when used in jdbc program

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I had inserted few rows into my table EMP using SQL client and also JDBC program. Records inserted using SQL client are not showing up in the output console of Java.

I'm using Java 8 and oracle 11g database to do inserting and reading database

I except all the record inserted both through SQL client and JDBC should show up

Comment: are you using transactions and committing the records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Un`COMMIT`ted data is only visible within the session that created it (and will `ROLLBACK` at the end of the session if it has not been `COMMIT`ted). If you can't see the data then make sure you have issued a `COMMIT` command in the SQL client.

If you have issued a `COMMIT` and still can't see the data then make sure that both the SQL Client and the JDBC program are connecting to the same database and are querying the same user's schema of that database.