# Getting Exausted ResultSet Error in Java jdbc oracle

Tags: java, oracle, exception, jdbc, resultset

This is the code for jdbc which is written in eclipse. I am just trying to store the result of the query to ResultSet rs and adding it to String name. But on execution the below code i am facing Exhausted Resultset error.

```java
import java.sql.*;

public class DemoClass{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        
        String query = "SELECT name FROM Emp WHERE rollno=1";

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe", "Subhro", "Kabiraj");
        
        Statement st = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery(query);
        rs.next();
        String name = rs.getString("name");
        
        System.out.println(name);
        
        st.close();
        con.close();
    }
}
```

> ***ERROR:***

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
    at ojdbc6@11.2.0.4/oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1270)
    at ojdbc6@11.2.0.4/oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet.getString(OracleResultSet.java:498)
    at DemoClass.main(DemoClass.java:14)
```

Note: my table is not empty.

TABLE created in terninal:

```
SQL> INSERT INTO Emp(rollno, name) values(1, 'abc');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO Emp(rollno, name) values(2, 'def');

1 row created.

SQL> INSERT INTO Emp(rollno, name) values(3, 'ghi');

1 row created.

SQL> select * from Emp
  2  ;

    ROLLNO
----------
NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1
abc

     2
def

     3
ghi


SQL> SELECT name FROM Emp WHERE rollno=1;

NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc
```

Any suggestions how to get rid of this error.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/57705007/1509264

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un`COMMIT`ted data is only visible within the session that created it (and will `ROLLBACK` at the end of the session if it has not been `COMMIT`ted). If you can't see the data then make sure you have issued a `COMMIT` command in the SQL client.

If you have issued a `COMMIT` and still can't see the data then make sure that both the SQL Client and the JDBC program are connecting to the same database and are querying the same user's schema of that database.